# iCloud setup on Mac - What password to use in last step

Tags: macos, icloud, mojave, filevault

I have iCloud turned off on my Mac, and now I want to turn it on. In the first step, it wants my Apple ID and password, in 2nd step it wants my Mac user password but in 3rd step it wants password to unlock my Mac.

To be honest, I'm not pretty sure what password should I use in last step - is it FileVault password or maybe some other password?

Screen from last step looks like this (sorry it's in Polish language)

[image]

Comment: This is the login password for the MacBook Pro it's referencing. That should be the same as the FileVault password on *that* MacBoook Pro. Click the blue text at the bottom to switch to another device if you need to.

Comment: @EzekielElin Thanks for comment. But is the FileVault password not the same as user or admin password? It seems user and admin password won't work so I believe the only password I have is some password generated by Macbook to access Filevault if user password was forgotten but I don't have access to it at the moment. Should it be this password?

Comment: On current version of macOS FileVault password is the same, is that not how it is on your computer? If you can't find a password that works, do you have other devices?

Comment: @EzekielElin No, I don't have any devices added to this AppleId. I've already tried my current user password and admin password. I will try with FileVault restore password once I get access to it.